# Diophantine equation $x^3+x+y^3+y = z^3 + z$ for $x,y,z>0$

Tags: diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

Consider the Diophantine equation $x^3+x+y^3+y = z^3 + z$ for positive integer $x,y,z$.

I tried small values and got some near equalities : $(5,6,7)$ and $(12,16,18)$ are true up to value $2$. $( 5^3 + 5 + 6^3 + 6 = 7^3 + 7 + 2 )$.

$(6,8,9)$ is true up to value $4$. And it appears that there are infinite near misses having a value of $80$ or $12$ or a power of $2$.

I already tried to find a contradiction mod $30$ and mod $7$ but did not find any.

I noticed that $x^3 + x$ can be squarefree and I cannot find infinite descent.

Does the polynomial ($x^3+x+y^3+y -(z^3 + z)$) factor perhaps ?  It is irreducible in $Z$ though.

I must note that I can solve the similar looking $x^3 -x + y^3 -y = z^3 - z$ over the integers which is also irreducible over $Z$.
(for instance by letting $z = u+v$ and $x = u - v$ reducing a subset of the solutions to a Pell equation )

Maybe Im close. I would like to solve this Diophantine without using p-adic.

And I also wonder about $x^3 + x + y^3 + y - z^3 - z = (12,80,2^n)$ and $x^5 + x + y^5 + y = z^5 + z$ for $x,y,z>0$.

Comment: Thanks, Raymond. Yes, there's an infinite number of positive integer solutions to $x^3 + x = y^3 + y + z^3 + z$ where {$x,y,z$} = {$u + v,\, u - v,\, 8v$} and $u^2-85v^2=1$.

Comment: Thank you. But I wonder how where 85 comes from ?
Does it pop out when you plug in the u and v ?
Did you find this 85 by trial and error or was there a method ?

Comment: It's not mine. It's by L. Aubry from a century ago. More generally, $x^3+y^3+z^3\pm(x+y+z) = 0$ where $$x,\,y,\,z =u+v,\;-u+v,\;-2v(3n+1)$$ if $u^2-(36n^3+36n^2+12n+1)v^2 =\pm n$. (Just change signs and move terms around to make them positive.) The $85$ is the case $n=1$, though curiously it also "pops" up in another cubic identity $a^3+b^3+c^3 = 1$ found by Ramanujan. See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381111/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some 'brute force' solutions of $\ x^3 + x + y^3 + y - z^3 - z = r$
(with additional contributions from Oleg567)

For $\ r=0\ $ (and $z<10^5$) :
\begin{array} {cc|c}
x&y&z\\
\hline
36& 37& 46\\
98& 248& 253\\
165& 705& 708\\
320& 377& 442\\
843& 1078& 1228\\
2372& 3323& 3685\\
2988& 3070& 3817\\
6963& 8320 & 9703 \\
8997 & 20636 & 21191 \\
24338 & 27272 & 32617 \\
28783 & 29763 & 36892 \\
39697 & 50635 & 57728 \\
41488 & 66006 & 71071 \\
55682 & 74983 & 84072 \\
\end{array}

(for general solutions see $16$. of [part 11](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/011) of Tito Piezas III ['Collection of Algebraic Identities'](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/Home))

For $\ r=12$ :
\begin{array} {cc|c}
x&y&z\\
\hline
1& 2& 0\\
72& 141& 147\\
\end{array}

For $\ r=80$ :
\begin{array} {cc|c}
x&y&z\\
\hline
11& 20& 21\\
18& 30 &32 \\
216& 644& 652\\
704& 781& 938\\
\end{array}

For $\ r=2^0\ $ none found ($\max(x,y)<10^4$).

For $\ r=2^1$ :
\begin{array} {cc|c}
x&y&z\\
\hline
1& u& u\\
5& 6& 7\\
12& 16& 18\\
101& 218& 225\\
215& 377& 399\\
\end{array}

For $\ r=2^2$ :
\begin{array} {cc|c}
x&y&z\\
\hline
1& 1& 0\\
6& 8& 9\\
\end{array}

For $\ r=2^3$ :
\begin{array} {cc|c}
x&y&z\\
\hline
9& 10& 12\\
17& 40& 41\\
92& 509& 510\\
568& 1104& 1152\\
2177& 2599& 3032\\
\end{array}

For $\ r=2^4$ :
\begin{array} {cc|c}
x&y&z\\
\hline
9& 15& 16\\
130& 199& 216\\
214& 274& 312\\
\end{array}

For $\ r=2^5$ :
\begin{array} {cc|c}
x&y&z\\
\hline
1573& 2897& 3044\\
4857& 7281& 7940\\
\end{array}

---

I found no solution to $\ x^5 + x + y^5 + y = z^5 + z$
(in the reduced range checked $\max(x,y)<10^4$).

Similar kinds of equations were much studied at the beginning of the 20th century. Dickson's famous books "History Of The Theory Of Numbers" may be consulted online (and downloaded) at [archive.org](http://archive.org/search.php?query=DICKSON%20History%20of%20the%20theory%20of%20numbers). 
Perhaps that the methods proposed [around these pages](http://archive.org/stream/historyoftheoryo02dickuoft#page/598/mode/2up) could inspire you... 
or Tito Piezas III since he appears from time to time [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4781/tito-piezas-iii) or at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/users/12905/tito-piezas-iii).

Comment: LOL i checked upto x = 35 ! However I think you missed solutions for r=12 and r=80. Thanks for the answer.
However I would like a 'theory' too. Brute force is the computer beating the human. ( I did not look at Tito's page at the time of comment ) There is also r = 2^n left.

Comment: @Mick: yeah but I was cautious (I wrote 'some') and for $2^n$ I'll add some answers too (don't hope an infinity... ;-)).

Comment: Hehe I do not hope for infinity in a finite world.

Comment: ok. You (please). and I will delete my comment after. I tried to find solution for 5-th degree, but without success too.

Comment: @Oleg567: Perhaps that we may prove that none exist at all for the 5-th degree (after all the OP wants formulas and proofs...). Thanks for the addition anyway,