# Where does this identity come from: $\left(x^2+7xy-9y^2\right)^3+\left(2x^2-5xy+12y^2\right)^3=\left(2x^2+10y^2\right)^3+\left(x^2-9xy-y^2\right)^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

I came across this identity 
$$\left(x^2+7xy-9y^2\right)^3+\left(2x^2-5xy+12y^2\right)^3=\left(2x^2+10y^2\right)^3+\left(x^2-9xy-y^2\right)^3$$

Is there a deeper reason why a formula such as this should exist?

Is there some background where the search for it could be motivated, and that it would come naturally?

Comment: From the goddess Namagiri. :)

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.39.9228&rep=rep1&type=pdf ... see the end of page 9 & page 10 ... Oh & there are lots of other gems too.

Comment: Regarding the comment from Deepak:... Sriinivasa Ramanujan actually did say that the goddess sent him math as he slept and it is true that he often could not explain  his methods of  discovery. For more on this extraordinary genius I recommend the memoir about him by G.H.Hardy .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of many Number Theoretic identities that mathematician [Ramanujan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan) discovered. It's hard to say exactly what the "deeper reason" such a formula exists, but it was most likely discovered in search of generalized families of [Taxicab numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number). The formula shows a method to write a number as in two distinct ways as a sum of two separate cube numbers. For example:
\begin{align*}
1729 &= 1^3 + 12^3 \\
     &= 9^3 + 10^3 \\
87539319 &= 167^3 + 436^3 \\
         &= 228^3 + 423^3 \\
         &= 255^3 + 414^3.
\end{align*}
(See if you can find which $x,\: y$, and $z$ you need to reach these solutions!)

As a few commentors have pointed out, Ramanujan claimed to have [received many formulas like these from the goddess Namagiri](https://www.scienceandnonduality.com/article/the-secrets-of-ramanujans-garden), the Hindu Goddess of creativity. It's an interesting bit of mathematical history that I think you would be delighted to learn. Ramanujan was truly an incredible mind.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry for the late reply, I was inactive for about 4 years. Anyway, most of Ramanujan's results are special cases of more general and perhaps deeper phenomena.

---

**I. 3rd powers**

For your question, a more general algebraic identity is,

$$A^3+B^3+C^3+D^3 = (a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3)(x^2+wy^2)^3$$

and $(A,B,C,D)$ are quadratic forms,

\begin{align}
A &= ax^2-v_1xy+bwy^2\\
B &= bx^2+v_1xy+awy^2\\ 
C &= cx^2+v_2xy+dwy^2\\ 
D &= dx^2-v_2xy+cwy^2
\end{align}

where {$v_1,\, v_2,\, w$} = {$c^2-d^2,\; a^2-b^2,\; (a+b)(c+d).$} I gave [this identity](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation3rdPowers.html) to Mathworld about 20 years ago.

Thus, given a **single** example of $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3 =N$ where $N=0$, a cube, or any number of cubes, then one can generate an *infinite* more via the **LHS**. For example, try it with the well-known $3^3+4^3+5^3+(-6)^3 = 0$, permute these variables $(a,b,c,d)$ in any order you wish, and you'll have your own Ramanujan-type identity of sums of cubes.

---

**II. 4th powers**

Ramanujan also gave,

$$(2x^2+12xy-6y^2)^4+(2x^2-12xy-6y^2)^4+(4x^2-12y^2)^4+(4x^2+12y^2)^4+(3x^2+9y^2)^4 = (5x^2+15y^2)^4$$

that for $(x,y)=(1,0)$ yields the nice,

$$2^4+2^4+4^4+4^4+3^4 = 5^4$$

The [general identity](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation4thPowers.html) (which I also gave to Mathworld) is,

$$A^4+B^4+C^4 = (a^4+b^4+c^4)(x^2+3y^2)^4$$

and $(A,B,C)$ are also quadratic forms,

\begin{align}
A &= ax^2+2(b+c)xy-3ay^2\\
B &= bx^2-2(a+c)xy-3by^2\\
C &= cx^2-2(a-b)xy-3cy^2\\
\end{align}

where $\color{brown}{a+b = c}$. Thus, given a single $a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4+e^4 =f^4$ where $a+b = c$, one can find an infinite more.

---

**P.S.** There's actually *another* cubic identity (as well as a $5$th-deg, but I'm too sleepy. I'll add it soon.) More details can be found at "*[Generalizing Ramanujan's sum of cubes identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/381111/4781)*"