# How do I Transform a Quadratic expression into a Pell Equation?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, pell-type-equations

I have been told that a simple linear transformation (or a change of variables) can transform the quadratic  $$x^2+45xy-216y^2$$ into the Pell equation $$p^2−321q^2=1$$ However I have been unable to achieve this.  Can anyone help me find a simple linear transformation (or a change of variables) to arrive at the Pell equation above? I want to eliminate the xy  term in the quadratic.

Comment: Complete the square & put some $'s around your formulae.

Comment: is the quadratic supposed to be an equation?

Comment: The quadratic is an expression and it is part of a larger cubic equation.

Comment: How do I  complete the square ?

Comment: $x^2+2cxy+dy^2=   (x+cy)^2+dy^2-c^2y^2$

Comment: I noticed that when you edited you changed the signs on $45$ and $216$

Comment: Yes I  corrected the sign. I made a mistake initially.  Does a sign change make a lot of difference ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner When I complete the square , according to the formula you have given, I end up with the Pell Equation $$ p^2 - 722.25 q^2 = 1 $$

Comment: Note that $722.25=321(1.5)^2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  Thank you very much. So the change of variables I wanted was 1.5y = q  and x+ 22.5 y = p .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=x+\dfrac{45}2y$ and $q=\dfrac32y$.

Then $p^2-321q^2=x^2+45xy+\dfrac{2025}4y^2-321\dfrac94y^2=x^2+45xy-216y^2.$

Comment: Im very late for this party, but in case you've ever wondered what the context of this apparently random Pell equation was, the OP came across [my 2013 post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381111/generalizing-ramanujans-sum-of-cubes-identity) on "Ramanujan's sum of cubes identity" and is trying to specialize the identity, $$(3(3p^2 - 104p q + 909q^2))^3 + (-2(4p^2 - 135p q + 1119q^2))^3 = (6(p^2 - 37p q + 348q^2))^3 + (p^2 - 321q^2)^3$$ to the form $a^3+b^3 = c^3+1$ by solving the Pell equation $p^2 - 321q^2 = 1$. More details in the link. Just in case you wondered. :)